# Cannot hit breakpoints in Visual Studio running x64 CPU

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, breakpoints

I am running a web app in a x64 CPU mode in VS 2015. I am mostly unable to add breakpoints. Even if I am able to, VS doesn't hit those breakpoints. I need to debug the application. What do I do?
BTW, I have tried attaching to process, still doesn't hit the breakpoints.

Comment: There is not much info here to help.  Do you have a web project open?  What kind?  What language(s)?  Are you trying to set breakpoints in the server code or client code?  What does "unable to add breakpoints" mean?  Do you get a breakpoint bind error?

Comment: @stylojack_10, if you couldn't add the breakpoint, please let me know where did you add it, maybe it is related to the project file you open or others. For another issue "breakpoint does not hit after you added the breakpoint successfully", please enable the Microsoft symbol server under Tools->Options->Debugging->Symbols. Or visit the Module window to load assembly manually. Of course, you could get more information from the output window during debugging.

Comment: @Patrick, I am unable to add breakpoints in my web application's C# code (aspx.cs files) on my local machine on Visual Studio. Breakpoints that can be added by pressing F9 in Visual Studio. I get no error, nothing. Visual Studio simply wont put a breakpoint. Is that enough info?

Comment: @Jack, I am trying to add breakpoints in my c# code to debug. I am using a _x64 CPU (in Visual Studio) since my Oracle is _x64.

Comment: @stylojack_10, do you get any warning or error messages if you put the mouse on the breakpoint during debugging time? Please also visit the output window. In addition, what is your windows Environment? How about changing the platform to be Any CPU? For the first issue, since you could add the breakpoint with shortcut key F9, please disable all breakpoint in the breakpoint window, and then reset your VS settings, and then re-add the breakpoint again without using the shortcut key.

Comment: @stylojack_10, I've never seen something like that.  You should be able to set a breakpoint in any text file - though it won't bind if there's no executable code associated with the location.  Is there a "Toggle Breakpoint" item in the Debug menu?  Can you set breakpoints in other project types?  If not, it's possible that your VS install is corrupt somehow.

Comment: I don't but somehow its working now. I don't know what to say. Among trying so many things, I don't know what made it work. Thanks for your support though.

Comment: @stylojack_10, glad to know it works well. Maybe you could share the main actions/steps you tried in your side as a answer for this issue, so it could help other members who meet the same issue to narrow down or resolve the same issue.

Comment: I wish I could, but I don't remember what I did exactly. Although I can say it involved restarting VS, IIS etc.